# Lyx how to call a local .sty file

Tags: lyx, packages

I created a `.sty` file that I used locally with a tex file.

I mean that I put the tex and the styfile on the same folder (in my documents) and call the styfile as a `\usepackage{mycustomstyfile}`

However I try to do the same in LyX by putting `\usepackage{mycustomstyfile}` in the preamble but it does not work. Someone can help me?

The LyX error message is

```
Undefined contorl sequence :   s
       kldafjkldfjksdfjl The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have misspelled
it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct spelling (e.g.,
`I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue, and I'll forget about whatever was
undefined.
```

Comment: I think it should work if you place the `.sty` in the same folder as the `.lyx`. Otherwise, see e.g. [Where do I place my own .sty files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137)

Comment: Hello if i place my .sty in the same folder as a .tex. it's perfectly working. But if I place my .sty in the same folder as the .lyx it is not working...

Comment: Ok, obviously I remembered wrongly. The method in that question I linked to should work though.

Comment: Placing in the same folder might work (or have worked in the past) in some special cases for LyX, but in general LyX copies files to a temporary directory before it does compilation. You can work around this in various ways, but the best solution by far is to make your TeX distribution aware of the sty file, as Torbjørn T. linked to.

Comment: Thanks! Placing `.sty` files in same folder as the` .lyx` file being edited worked for me (on MacOS Lyx v 2.2.2).